# Asterisks in the Pri Megadim

Tags: shulchan-aruch

What is meant by the stars/asterisks that are printed around some words/phrases in the Pri Megadim on the shulchan aruch? These asterisks/stars are found repeatedly on almost every page of the Pri Megadim - more so in Ohr Hachayim - in all editions of the shulchan aruch.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a star/asterisk? What edition are you looking at? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Mark opening a bounty is not going to help much if nobody knows what you are referring to. Perhaps consider adding a picture or at least one specific maareh makom of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 7):

This indicates a chiddush that he is writing. The same is true for "the finger" that sometimes appears.

See in his introduction in the first chelek of Orach Chaim [here:](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41247&st=&pgnum=2&hilite=)

The paragraph on the bottom right that starts 'הה

Comment: Do you know that שושן refers to an asterisk?

Comment: @mevaqesh Just an assumption. But probably a very good one because there are now flowers in his commentary and he does put an asterisk when he writes a chiddush and an asterisk does look like a flower.

Comment: @mevaqesh The same source in the Machon Yerushalayim edition of Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim Vol 1 includes an asterisk next to the word שושן, demonstrating that it is an asterisk. Perhaps they found it in an earlier edition of Pri Megadim, or they also made the same assumption...

Comment: You have me convinced. At least convinced enough  to upvote.